# Ubuntu 18.04 recuperado de paquetes borrados

Tags: ubuntu

Ejecuté este comando:

```
sudo apt-get remove lamp-server^
```

Ahora he borrado unos ficheros del sistema operativo y no puedo acceder con interfaz gráfica.

También me dice que xAuthority no existe a veces, aunque miro y el archivo sigue ahí, al arrancar me salen unos avisos como, entre otros:

> Error: ACPI Error: Aborting Method _SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC_QD2 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUNT) (20190703\psparse-531)

He intentado el comando: `startx`, `xinit`, `sudo apt install gnome-desktop`, no ha funcionado ninguno, el `install` de `gnome-desktop` no me encuentra los paquetes.

Fichero history.log:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fichero sources.list:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar con mayor exactitud sistema operativo y versión? Además, ¿podrías compartir el contenido del archivo `/var/log/apt/history.log`? También nos vendría bien el contenido de los archivos `sources.list` que hayas modificado para instalar el paquete `lamp-server`, ya que no es un paquete de los repositorios oficiales de Ubuntu.

Comment: Recuerda nombrar a una persona (poniendo un @ delante) en un comentario cuando hagas la modificación solicitada, para que recibamos una notificación. Bien, ese es el archivo y desde ahí puedes recuperar el estado anterior, pero necesito que eso sea texto. ¿Tienes acceso por SSH al servidor? Comparte todo como texto usando copiar/pegar y no capturas de pantalla. Gracias.

Comment: No tengo acceso a Internet ahora mismo en la máquina, desde que me pasó esto, no puedo conectarme a la red, no se hacerlo con comandos, he buscado pero utilizan comandos que debes tener previamente instalados y no tengo ranura RJ-45. @OscarGarcia

Comment: ¿Puedes probar un `ip addr list`? Si es por wifi es probable que no dispongas de conexión ni para recuperar el sistema. Lo mejor sería tratar de configurar a mano la conexión (mejor si es por ethernet que por wifi). A ver si alguien te puede ayudar a restablecer la conexión, yo puedo ayudarte con la recuperación de los últimos paquetes borrados. Siento no poder ayudarte ahora, pero se agotó mi tiempo. Hace tres horas y media disponía de tiempo para ayudarte, pero ahora tengo que irme.

Comment: Por cierto, una vez que te ayuden a tener conexión, debes hacer un `apt-get update` y luego un `apt-get install $(grep ^Remove: /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -n -1 | sed -r 's/^Upgrade: //; s/(([^ ]+) \([^\)]+\),?)/\2/g')`. Eso reinstalará lo último que borraste (`grep ^Remove: /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -n -1`) aunque lo marcará como manualmente instalado. La próxima vez que hagas un modificación así procura ver qué paquetes pide desinstalar. Y, por si las moscas, de vez en cuando haz un `dpkg --get-selections > copia_de_seguridad.txt`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Probaré con la conexión y luego probaré tu solución, muy amable.